# MBpro - Battery drain in sleep mode - Wake Reason : EC.USBC(Maintenance)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery

So I have a MacbookPro 2018 from septembre and a week ago, I noticed that my battery computer drain  really fast in sleep mode.

So I tried a lot of things like setting hibernatemode in 25 and other technics. But no way, yesterday I did a clean install and I got the same problem.

Yesterday night after the install, I had 100% battery at 00:00am and today morning at 06:00am, I had 0%.

So I tried to look at my console log and suprise I got a lot of logs that my computer awake but I don't understand my problem.

That's just a little fragment of this night.

```
2018-11-25 05:33:18.460174+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 05:33:18.460272+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 05:33:18.911411+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:33:19.456986+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:33:30.842556+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:33:30.842558+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:33:48.174439+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 05:33:48.174480+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 05:33:48.660653+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:33:49.219096+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:34:00.739746+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:34:00.739749+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:34:11.187658+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 05:34:11.187675+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 05:34:11.642610+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:34:12.238170+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:34:22.727978+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:34:22.727980+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:34:33.177361+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 05:34:33.177392+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 05:34:33.669393+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:34:34.215322+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:34:44.836631+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:34:44.836633+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:34:55.932435+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 05:34:55.932677+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 05:34:56.189035+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:34:56.978017+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:35:07.716666+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:35:07.716668+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:35:23.813081+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 05:35:23.813094+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 05:35:24.262532+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:35:24.848736+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:35:36.444512+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:35:36.444514+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:35:46.899014+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 05:35:46.899045+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 05:35:47.119153+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:35:47.918972+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:35:59.620020+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:35:59.620022+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:36:15.884352+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 05:36:15.884409+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 05:36:16.157697+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:36:16.931007+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:36:28.028370+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:36:28.028373+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:36:40.006415+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 05:36:40.006459+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 05:36:40.469284+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:36:41.044759+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:36:51.751827+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:36:51.751829+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:37:02.347217+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 05:37:02.347270+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 05:37:02.784267+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:37:03.376502+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:37:14.788451+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:37:14.788453+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:37:25.276392+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 05:37:25.276430+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 05:37:25.746539+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:37:26.326287+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:37:37.647755+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:37:37.647758+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:37:48.149272+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 05:37:48.149319+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 05:37:48.401782+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:37:49.199073+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:38:00.763522+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:38:00.763524+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:38:11.318351+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 05:38:11.318383+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 05:38:11.609960+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:38:12.358604+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:38:23.051602+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:38:23.051604+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:38:33.493034+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 05:38:33.493077+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 05:38:33.760863+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:38:34.536131+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Keyboard (0x02)

2018-11-25 05:38:45.992218+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 05:38:45.992220+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)





And that's today :



2018-11-25 16:37:43.406488+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:37:49.038326+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 16:37:49.038338+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 16:37:49.646558+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:37:49.956763+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:38:42.474391+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:38:42.474394+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:38:48.262273+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 16:38:48.262284+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 16:38:48.903515+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:38:49.186437+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:39:41.723856+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:39:41.723860+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:39:47.358764+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 16:39:47.358800+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 16:39:47.953708+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:39:48.271713+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:40:40.791484+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:40:40.791487+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:40:46.589847+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 16:40:46.589858+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 16:40:47.190462+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:40:47.506875+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:41:40.054109+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:41:40.054112+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:41:45.938222+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 16:41:45.938234+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 16:41:46.527549+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:41:46.850888+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:42:39.381155+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:42:39.381158+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:42:45.247101+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 16:42:45.247112+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 16:42:45.871410+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:42:46.159949+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:43:38.691028+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:43:38.691032+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:43:44.801081+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 16:43:44.801092+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 16:43:45.446744+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:43:45.711596+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:44:38.251439+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:44:38.251442+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:44:44.315303+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 16:44:44.315314+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 16:44:44.934664+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:44:45.225609+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:45:37.732424+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:45:37.732427+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:45:39.414369+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>

2018-11-25 16:45:39.414381+0100  localhost corespeechd[907]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemon _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3

2018-11-25 16:45:40.029631+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:45:40.329813+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Button (0x03)

2018-11-25 16:46:32.877084+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)

2018-11-25 16:46:32.877088+0100  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: EC.USBC (Maintenance)
```

I'm really lost and I really need my computer. Apple is know to have a good sleep mode and battery life. My macbook have just 3 months.

Thanks for answer !

Comment: Were you able to get it resolved? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Does your computer pass Apple Hardware Test (press d on boot)? Did you enable Siri or other voice services?