# Why does MacBook Pro battery discharge when not in use?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake

I generally keep my 2018 MacBook Pro plugged in and I use it casually when not plugged in throughout the day.

With light email checking in Safari throughout the day, I have gone from 35% to 13% today. This includes large jumps that decrease **while the computer is closed**.

Because I am aware of this problem, I tried closing the lid when not in use, also Power Nap While Using Battery is disabled.

My previous computer was a 2015 MacBook Air. I used that in a similar way and was able to use it entirely untethered from power for the entire week.

*How can I diagnose battery usage for the times that the computer is closed?*

---

**Related**

- I do also see log events from time periods when the computer should be sleeping. For example, last night the computer was not plugged in and I was sleeping but Apple and/or the NSA decided this was a good time for com.apple.telemetry to make 100+ log entries. This is discussed at
  [MBpro - Battery drain in sleep mode - Wake Reason : EC.USBC(Maintenance)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/343765/mbpro-battery-drain-in-sleep-mode-wake-reason-ec-usbcmaintenance) with no responses. I do not have a reason to believe this contributes significantly to my battery issue.

Comment: There's already a lot of answers on this site to help with battery problems & troubleshooting.  Have you tried any of those yet?  If so, what have you tried (so we don't ask you to repeat the same steps)?

Comment: The macbook pro is not the same as a macbook air... also it may be still completing background tasks.

Comment: @fsb Thank you, I have added notes about the one I checked before posting this